# Simple Web Server C#

Tags: c#, webserver

I need some help with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
namespace HttpEcho
{
  class HttpEchoProgram
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80);
      server.Start();
      Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Client...");
      TcpClient newConn = server.AcceptTcpClient();
      IPEndPoint iep = (IPEndPoint)(newConn.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
      IPAddress add = iep.Address;
      int prt = iep.Port;
      Console.WriteLine("Connected with a client: {0}: {1} ", add, prt);
      NetworkStream stream = newConn.GetStream();
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
      StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
      sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      sw.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/plain");
      //sw.WriteLine("Content-Length: size");
      sw.WriteLine();
      String line = null;
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()).Length != 0)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        sw.WriteLine(line);
        sw.Flush();
      }
      newConn.Close();
      server.Stop();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to modify this code so it can work as a Simple Web Server that it fetches requested page in the local file system and returns it to the browser.

Comment: Learn HTTP protocol. Read and parse the request which would have a resource name. Respond with the contents of the requested resource.

Answer (score 8):

You can save yourself a few thousand lines of code by starting with a HttpListener instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx